# BeanCreationException on creating @manytomany entity relationship

Tags: java, spring-boot, entity-relationship

I am creating three tables Doctor,Patient and Specialty. Patients can have exactly one GP, but one doctor can be a GP of many patients. Each Doctor has it's specialty(e.g. neurosurgeon,cardiologist,urologist etc.) When I try to make the many-to-many connection between Doctor and Specialty with a middle table I get an error "Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource" caused by BeanCreationException in particular mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property. Since I am new to spring boot I would be really happy if someone can explain me. Thank you in advance

BaseEntity class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
}
```

Doctor class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="doctor")
public class Doctor extends BaseEntity{

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy ="doctor")
    private Set<Specialty> specialties;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy ="doctor")
    private List<Patient> GpOfPatients;

}
```

Patient class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="patient")
public class Patient extends BaseEntity{

    private String name;
    private String EGN;
    private boolean insurancesPaidInLastSixMonths;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="gp_id")
    private Doctor doctor;

}
```

Specialty class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="specialty")
public class Specialty extends BaseEntity{

    private String specialtyName;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="doctors_specialties",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="specialty_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="doctor_id"))
    private Set<Doctor> doctors;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Doctor class, you mapped `specialties` with `doctor`, but in Specialty, the name of Doctor set is `doctors`, so they cannot be mapped.

You should change your Doctor class as shown below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="doctor")
public class Doctor extends BaseEntity{

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy ="doctors")
    private Set<Specialty> specialties;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy ="doctor")
    private List<Patient> GpOfPatients;

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, finally a solution. I've searched everywhere and still was not able to find where was the mistake.